# Scala: slice a list from the first non-zero element

Tags: list, scala

Suppose I have a list filled with zeroes

```
val a = List(0,0,0,0,2,4,0,6,0,7)
```

I want to slice away the zeroes preceding the first non-zero element and also return the index where the 1st non-zero element is present.
Foe the above case I want an output:

```
output = List(2,4,0,6,0,7)
idx = 4
```

How do I do it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I was trying to use .takewhile fn but it was of no use. I would prefer not to have recursion in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dropWhile`:

```
val output = a.dropWhile{ _ == 0 }
val idx = output.headOption
  .map(_ => a.length - output.length)
  .getOrElse(-1) // index starting from 0, -1 if not found
```

Comment: I think calculating the index by subtracting lengths is not the best approach for this problem. My answer uses `indexWhere` which calculates the index with no manual manipulation on numbers.

Comment: @OfekHod sure, your approach looks simple, but requires some additional logic

Comment: I think you are wrong about it and it does not require additional logic, please check out my comment in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use `zipWithIndex` to conveniently pair each element with its index. Then use `dropWhile` to return all of the preceding zero elements. From there, you'll have all of the remaining elements paired with their indices from the original `List`. You can `unzip` them. Since this may result in an empty list, the index you're looking for should be optional.

```
scala> val (remaining, indices) = a.zipWithIndex.dropWhile { case (a, i) => a == 0 }.unzip
remaining: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 0, 6, 0, 7) // <--- The list you want
indices: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val index = indices.headOption
index: Option[Int] = Some(4) // <--- the index of the first non-zero element
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a use-case for span:

```
val a = List(0,0,0,0,2,4,0,6,0,7)

val (zeros, output) = a.span(_ == 0)
val idx = zeros.length
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it pretty clean with `indexWhere`:

```
val idx = a.indexWhere(_!=0)
val output = a.drop(idx)
```

Comment: it falls on input: `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`. `indexWhere` returns 0, but drop returns `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4) with zero`

Comment: Hey @BorisAzanov you are wrong, in this case the first index which is not `0` is `idx=1`, so `drop(1)` will remove the first `0` and returns `List(1, 2, 3, 4)` with `idx=1`, which is the right answer for that case. I just ran your example to make sure it works.

Comment: you are right. Your code is correct. One minus in your decision is twice reading zeros prefix, `indexWhere` and `drop` both reading first `k` zeros, but it's not necessary, once is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution using foldLeft:

```
val (i, l) =
  a.foldLeft((None: Option[Int], List.empty: List[Int]))((b, n) => {
    if (n == 0 && b._2.isEmpty) (b._1.orElse(Some(0)).map(_ + 1), List.empty)
    else (b._1.orElse(Some(0)), b._2 :+ n)
  })
i: Option[Int] = Some(4)
l: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 0, 6, 0, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sightly modified from @bottaio answer, but returning an **Option[Int]** instead of a plain **Int** for the index.

```
def firstNonZero(l: List[Int]): (Option[Int], List[Int]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(remaining: List[Int], idx: Int): (Int, List[Int]) =
    remaining match {
      case Nil     => idx -> Nil
      case 0 :: xs => go(remaining = xs, idx + 1)
      case xs      => idx -> xs
    }

  l match {
    case 0 :: xs =>
      val (idx, list) = go(remaining = xs, idx = 1)
      Some(idx) -> list

    case list =>
      None -> list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided answers that requires multiple list traversals. You can write a recursive function to calculate that in a single pass:

```
def firstNonZero(l: List[Int]): (Int, List[Int]) = {
  @tailrec
  def go(l: List[Int], idx: Int): (Int, List[Int]) = l match {
    case Nil => (idx, Nil)
    case 0 :: xs => go(xs, idx + 1)
    case xs => (idx, xs)
  }

  go(l, 0)
}
```

what is also equivalent to

```
val (leadingZeros, rest) = a.span(_ == 0)
val (index, output) = (leadingZeros.length, rest)
```

Comment: This has just a minor problem, it returns idx as `0` when the list is empty or when there are not any zeros, and maybe it should be `-1` or I would rather return an **Option**.

Comment: Option would probably be most generic - users could decide how they want to handle that case

Comment: @BorisAzanov so for that reason you downvote a perfectly valid answer, which btw is pretty more efficient than yours. OP is to decide if he/she prefers a hand made tailrec function or one using standard library methods.

Comment: first decision is too long for such simple task and requires tests/docs.
second decision is bad if we have very long zeros prefix, it consumes a lot of memory in this case, `dropWhile` doesn't consume a lot - just only what needs.

Comment: @BorisAzanov _"excessive"_ is quite a big word. _"more code == more bugs"_ partially true, but it is a point nevertheless. In any case, it still doesn't deserve a downvote. If you do not consider it a good solution that is ok, just do not upvote it; and if you feel you have a valid criticism you may add it as a comment _(as you did)_. But a downvote should only be reserved for answers that didn't solve the problem, or use bad practices or something more tangible rather than just:  _"I do not like this way of programming"_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez okay, you are right, I updated answer and will not down vote this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez decision from two lines easier to test than recursive functions, more readable and more obviously. On memory I sad  about `span `, it consumes memory for unused list  `leadingZeros` but we only need to know length of this list, not elements.

Comment: _"decision from two lines easier to test than recursive functions"_ why? if you encapsulate everything in method _(which you should)_ you have to test both the same way, it doesn't have any impact if it is just one line long, you test input vs output. - _"On memory I sad about `span`"_  ok fair enough, you may be more clear about that, but anyway, I will leave this discussion here since it is not appropriate for SO and it is not bringing any value at all.